# My USB Flash Drive is seen as a fixed disk. How can I add the "removable bit" to my drive to make it bootable?

Tags: usb, bootable-media, removable-media

I am using:

- Windows 8
- Walgreens EasyStore 16gb USB 2.0 Flash Drive (Sandisk internals from my research)
- Windows 7 USB DVD Download Tool

The flash drive is seen as a fixed disk in Windows, which makes it unbootable.

How can I add the "removable bit" to my drive to make it bootable?

Comment: Make it bootable or make it removable?  They are two entirely different things.

Comment: found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, I misread your question on my first answer. I'm sure there is relatively easy fix but I'm not using Windows 8. As there have been no other answers forthcoming, I'd advise using a program called [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to create the bootable USB pen.